# MySQL returns table name instead of value with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make an AJAX request to fetch some data from the database but the only thing returned is the name of the column. Can somebody explain why?
Here is my code:

**=> Table Name :- tblstudents**

```
id = 0
fname = john
lname = doe
tel = 555-564-1585

id = 1 
fname = paul
lname = smith
tel = 555-134-5644

id = 2
fname = laura
lname = mcdo
tel = 555-465-7512
```

**=> AJAX method:**

```
function fetchFromDBPHP(column, fname, id, tel) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "./php/fetchFromDB.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { column: column, fname: fname, id: id },
        success: function(data) {
            localStorage.setItem(tel, data);
        },
        error:function(request, status, error) {
            console.log("** Error from fetchFromDBPHP **");
            console.log("Error: " + error + "\nMessage: " + request.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

**=> Javascript :**

```
fetchFromDBPHP(column, fname, id, "one");
var result = localStorage.getItem("one");
console.log("Result: " + result);
```

**=> PHP :**

```
<?php
    $column = $_POST['column'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    if (isset($column)) {
        $sql = "SELECT '$column' FROM tblstudents WHERE fname = '$fname' AND id = '" . intval($id) . "'";
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
        if (!$con) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error($con));
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $to_encode = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
            $to_encode[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($to_encode);
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

As you might know, `column`, `fname` and `id` have values in the Javascript code. As my database is way longer, I tried to be as much close as possible to my real code. The only thing is, the result of the AJAX request gives me a JSON object result containing the name of the column, and not its content. 
Anybody can help?  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you show us the actual JSON?  My guess is that perhaps you have an empty result set, with column labels and no data.

Comment: Note that AJAX is async, so you can't access it's result right after calling it, you have to put your `console.log` inside the `success` callback. Otherwise the request will still be in progress at that time.

Comment: `SELECT '$column'` is wrong. It should be `SELECT \`$column\`` (back ticks instead of single quotes). However, you are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all! _Never ever_ trust user inputs. Regarding the column name, which you can't parameterize, you should create a white list with allowed column names.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, you are ABSOLUTELY right! The back ticks are the solution ! THANKS YOU VERY MUCH!! :)

Comment: I agree, the code is wide open to SQL Injections. I have some better code to use Prepared Statements. Thanks again for your help! Where can I give you my vote ?

Comment: I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong quotes in your query.

```
"SELECT '$column' FROM ..."
```

...will simply return the value of the variable `$column` instead of the value of the actual  database column.

Changing it to (back ticks):

```
"SELECT `$column` FROM ..."
```

will work.

#### An important note...

...the posted code is wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenation of the variables in the query. Specially since the user inputs aren't escaped at all.

Rule of thumb, *never ever* trust user inputs.

Regarding the column name, which you can't parameterize, you should create a white list with allowed column names.